# Hi, I am facing these two errors for my POST method. HttpClientErrorException$MethodNotAllowed and HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest

Tags: spring-boot, rest, servlets

`**This is my CreateCustomer Service which is facing the issue.**

```
package assignment.SunbaseData.Service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import assignment.SunbaseData.model.Customer;

@Service
public class CreateCustomer implements PostService {

String createUrl="https://qa2.sunbasedata.com/sunbase/portal/api/assignment.jsp";

 @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;




public String createCus(String token,Customer customer) {
    HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
     headers.setBearerAuth(token);
    
     restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
     String cmd="create";
    
     createUrl=createUrl+"?cmd="+cmd;
    
        
        HttpEntity<Customer> entity = new HttpEntity<>(customer, headers);
        
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(createUrl, HttpMethod.POST,   entity,String.class);         
       
        
        return response.toString();

  
    
}





@Override
public String getToken(String login, String password) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public List<Object> getCustomer(String token) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}






    }`
```

**This is my Controller so far**

```
package assignment.SunbaseData.Controller;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

 import assignment.SunbaseData.Service.CreateCustomer;
 import assignment.SunbaseData.Service.FetchingCustomer;
 import assignment.SunbaseData.Service.TokenService;
 import assignment.SunbaseData.model.Customer;

 import java.util.List;

 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value="/api/v1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public class Controller {
   String generatedToken="";
  private TokenService tokenService=new TokenService();
  private FetchingCustomer fetchCustomer=new FetchingCustomer();
  private CreateCustomer createCustomer=new CreateCustomer();



    //for getting the authentication token using RestTemplate
  @PostMapping(value="/auth")
  public String getToken(){
            String response= tokenService.getToken("test@sunbasedata.com","Test@123");
          try {
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(response);
              JsonNode node = tree.get("access_token");
              generatedToken = node.textValue().toString();
          }
          catch (Exception e){
              generatedToken=null;
          }

        

          return generatedToken;
}

@PostMapping(value="/create")
public String NewCustomer( Customer customer) {
    String response=createCustomer.createCus(generatedToken,new Customer("piyush","Dasila","Vaibhav Khand","630 Siena Tower mahagun Mansion","Ghaziabad","UttarPradesh","piyush.dasilawork@gmail.com","9711126274"));
    
    return response;
}


 
 
public void updateCustomer(){

}
//for getting all the customers
@GetMapping(value="/customers")
public List<Object> getCustomers(){
    List<Object> response=fetchCustomer.getCustomer(generatedToken);
            return response;

}
public void deleteCustomer(){

}
}
```

`

**This is my fetching the authentication token Service and use it for other endpoints**
``

```
          package assignment.SunbaseData.Service;
           import java.util.Arrays;
          import java.util.List;

          import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
     import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
     import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
     import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
     import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
     import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
     import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
     import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

     import assignment.SunbaseData.model.Customer; 

      @Service
     public class FetchingCustomer implements PostService{

private String getUrl="https://qa2.sunbasedata.com/sunbase/portal/api/assignment.jsp";

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;




@Override
public List<Object> getCustomer(String token) {
    
    restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
    
    HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    
    String cmd="get_customer_list";
    
     getUrl=getUrl+"?cmd="+cmd;
     
     headers.setBearerAuth(token);
     
      HttpEntity<Object[]> et2=new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Object[]> responseEntity2 = restTemplate.exchange(
                getUrl,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                et2,
                Object[].class
        );
        
        Object[] response=responseEntity2.getBody();
        if (response != null) {
            return Arrays.asList(response);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Fetching cutomer has failed");
        }
  }
@Override
public String getToken(String login, String password) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public String createCus(String token,Customer customer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return null;
}
   }``
```

**This is my Fetching all the customers from the external API Service**

```
    `  
       package assignment.SunbaseData.Service;

      import java.util.Arrays;
     import java.util.List;

       import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
       import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
     import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
        import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
      import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
     import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
       import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

      import assignment.SunbaseData.model.Customer;

      public class FetchingCustomer implements PostService{
 
     private String getUrl="https://qa2.sunbasedata.com/sunbase/portal/api/assignment.jsp";
 
  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;




  @Override
  public List<Object> getCustomer(String token) {
    
    restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
    
    HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    
    String cmd="get_customer_list";
    
     getUrl=getUrl+"?cmd="+cmd;
     
     headers.setBearerAuth(token);
     
      HttpEntity<Object[]> et2=new HttpEntity<>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Object[]> responseEntity2 = restTemplate.exchange(
                getUrl,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                et2,
                Object[].class
        );
        
        Object[] response=responseEntity2.getBody();
        if (response != null) {
            return Arrays.asList(response);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Fetching cutomer has failed");
        }
  }
  @Override
  public String getToken(String login, String password) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
   @Override
 public String createCus(String token,Customer customer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return null;
}


     }
`
```

**This is the Customer model which I am using to POST the Body on the External API with the Authorization Token.**

`

```
   package assignment.SunbaseData.model;

    public class Customer {
     private String first_name;
     private String last_name;
    private String street;
   private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String email;
    private String phone;

     public Customer(){

     }
    public Customer(String first_name, String last_name, String street, String address, String city, String state, String email, String phone) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.street = street;
    this.address = address;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

}
`

I am attaching the two errors I am facing.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQZj9.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXxCK.png)

**I am trying to do this with the CreateCustomer Service.**

```
Path: https://qa2.sunbasedata.com/sunbase/portal/api/assignment.jsp
Method: GET
Parameters:
cmd : get_customer_list
Header:
Authorization: Bearer token_recieved_in_authentication_API_call
Response: 200
[{
"first_name": "Jane",
"last_name": "Doe",
"street": "Elvnu Street",
"address": "H no 2 ",
"city": "Delhi",
"state": "Delhi",
"email": "sam@gmail.com",
"phone": "12345678"
}]
```

I surfed on the internet and I tried removing the requestMethod=get from the requestMapping anotation in the RestController but It did'nt help. I am new to SpringBoot So I might have made a silly mistake.